# How to filter rows in one excel based on another excel sheet using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excel sheets:

Excel1: `emp_list.xlsx`

| emp_name | role | Location | skills |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| emp1 | consultant | Boston | Python |
| emp2 | Manager | Boston | Python |
| emp3 | associate | North Carolina | Java |
| emp4 | analyst | Hudson | Python |

Excel2: `emp_skills.xlsx`

| skill_set |
| --- |
| Python |
| Python |
| Python |

I am trying to filter the rows of `excel1` which has skills mentioned in `excel2` and write the filtered rows to another output excel.

```
import pandas as pd

file1='emp_list.xlsx'
file2='emp_skills.xlsx'
df1=pd.read_excel(file1)
df2=pd.read_excel(file2)

filter_df=df1.loc[(df2['skill_set'].isin(df1['skills']))]
filter_df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

The above code is giving the error:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean series provided as indexer(index of the 
               boolean series and of the indexed object do not match)
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is problem need test column from `df1` by `df2` like:

```
filter_df=df1.loc[(df1['skill_set'].isin(df2['skills']))]
```